# Having Trouble Deploying Hadoop on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been having trouble deploying Hadoop on Google Cloud Platform on a Linux command line using the command: `./bdutil -e platforms/hdp/ambari_env.sh deploy`

I keep getting this error:

```
************* gcloud compute stdout *******************
NAME           ZONE           SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
hadoop-w-0-pd  us-central1-a  1500     pd-standard  READY

******************* gcloud compute stderr *******************
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hadoop-164401/zones/us-central1-a/disks/hadoop-w-0-pd].
INFO: Display format "table(name,
                    zone.basename(),
                    sizeGb,
                    type.basename(),
                    status)".

New disks are unformatted. You must format and mount a disk before it
can be used. You can find instructions on how to do this at:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' exceeded.  Limit: 2048.0

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' exceeded.  Limit: 2048.0


************ ERROR logs from gcloud compute stderr ************
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Could not fetch resource:

******************* Exit codes and VM logs *******************
Thu, Apr 13, 2017  9:52:10 PM: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=hadoop-164401 --quiet --verbosity=info compute disks create --size=1500 --type=pd-standard hadoop-w-1-pd --zone=us-central1-a
Thu, Apr 13, 2017  9:52:10 PM: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=hadoop-164401 --quiet --verbosity=info compute disks create --size=1500 --type=pd-standard hadoop-m-pd --zone=us-central1-a
```

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment is exceeding the Quota limit (2048 GB) of persistent disks for your project. To resolve thes issue, you can:

- Edit configuration file of your deployment and specify lower sizes for PD disks resources.

Or

- Send a quota increase request to increase quota limit of the  PDs for your project.

Comment: thank you for your note. I don't understand how that could be the case, since in the  bdutil_env.sh file I have made the following specifications:  NUM_WORKERS=4
MASTER_ATTACHED_PD_SIZE_GB=10 MASTER_BOOT_DISK_SIZE_GB=10
And WORKER_BOOT_DISK_SIZE_GB=10
Please advise.

Comment: Last lines of your deployment log show that it's trying to create the master and workers nodes with PD sizes of 1500 GB. The reason is that the environmental variables in `ambari_manual_env.sh` and `ambari.conf` override the similar ones defined in `bdutil_env.sh`. Use `ambari_manual_env.sh` or `ambari.conf` instead.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. I now have: NUM_WORKERS=2 MASTER_ATTACHED_PD_SIZE_GB=200 MASTER_BOOT_DISK_SIZE_GB=200 And WORKER_BOOT_DISK_SIZE_GB=50 And I got this message:ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 8.0. Please advise

Comment: Looks like that you're deploying on a free trial account. As mentioned in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions), GCE CPU resources are limited to 8 cores for free trial accounts. So, in order to resolve the issue you can change `GCE_MACHINE_TYPE` value in `bdutil_env.sh` or `ambari_manual_env.sh` to a lighter [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).

Comment: thank you. Finally completed deployment. Couldn't have done it without you. Thanks a million!

Comment: Glad to hear you are up and running.

Comment: one more problem whenever I try to test hdfs comands I get this error: $ gcloud --project=hadoop-164401 compute ssh --zone=us-central1-a hadoop-m
Last login: Sun Apr 23 16:27:24 2017 from ool-44c0b1b0.dyn.optonline.net
[cbenne23@hadoop-m ~]$ hdfs
-bash: hdfs: command not found
[cbenne23@hadoop-m ~]$

Any advice.

Comment: also I noticed that when other folks open a shell with the command "gcloud --project=hadoop-164401 compute ssh --zone=us-central1-a hadoop-m" or "./bdutil shell", they get the following note: Warning: "Permanently added '130.211.132.0'(RSA) to the list of known hosts" but I use the same command I get the note:"Last login: Sun Apr 23 15:38:33 2017 from ool-44c0b1b0.dyn.optonline.net". Do you know the reason why my message is different from theirs

Comment: If you can not find `hdfs` command tool then your deployment is partially done. Before deploying again reboot the VM that you're using to deploy your Hadoop cluster. For your other question, please visit [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-known-hosts-file-for-ssh?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you. I deleted my old project and created a new project and did the deployment from scratch all over again. And everything seems to be working now. However, I have one concern, I got the following message: $ ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 hadoop-m.us-central1-a.hdp-506-165608
bind: Operation not permitted
What does bind:operation not permitted mean?

Comment: Looks like your account has not permission to do the operation. Can you try the command with `sudo` in front to see if it helps?